# What's the purpose of the highlighted part in the LED circuit?

Tags: led

I am reading a FPGA dev-board schematic, particularly for the LED part (below). I don't understand the purpose of the highlighted part (a 2.5v DC source and a resistor R584).

[image: LED circuit]

The full schematic can be downloaded from [here](https://gitee.com/xiongyuwu/docs/blob/master/fpga/BOE_V1.1.pdf). Btw, I called it "dev-board" because I use it for learning FPGA. The original project for this board seems related to [this](https://github.com/hpb-project/BOE), which is sort of dead (I think). The board was bought from a second-hand market, with schematic pdf.

The following is a picture of that part of the board. The LEDs is not populated, and I soldered 4 pins (using as GPIOs instead).

[image: board picture]

Comment: `a FPGA dev-board schematic` could you put a link to that, so we can see the rest of the circuit?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a link to the FPGA dev-board? Perhaps one of ``R584`` and ``R669`` are not fitted, and allow for build variations.

Comment: Updated with link to full schematic pdf, thanks.

Comment: The schematic uses ``DNP`` on some components for do-not-populate. There is no ``DNP`` for ``R584`` and ``R669`` which suggests both resistors are supposed to be populated. Do the LEDs in ``HL8`` turn on when there is a logic high at the corresponding FPGA pins? If so, I can't see what purpose ``R584`` serves. Also, is there a silkscreen on the PCB, and if so can you tell if both ``R584`` and ``R669`` are actually fitted?

Comment: @Chester I upload a picture of the LED part. I guess R584 and R669 are both fitted. I also tested the 4 pins with UART, they are all working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FPGA GPIOs are connected to pins 1, 3, 5 and 7 of what was the location for a Kingbright [L-914CK/4GDT 2x3mm QUAD-LEVEL LED INDICATOR](https://www.kingbright.com/attachments/file/psearch/000/00/20160808bak/L-914CK-4GDT(Ver.10B).pdf), via 330 \$\Omega\$ series resistors. These pins are the anodes for the LEDs.

`R584` and `R669` are connected to pins 2, 4, 6 and 8 of what are the cathodes of the LEDs. `R669` is zero \$\Omega\$ and provides the connection of the LED cathodes to ground. `R584` is 10 K\$\Omega\$ and is effectively just connected between ground and +2.5 V and serves no purpose when used with the Kingbright L-914CK/4GDT.

The question has clarified that the LED `HL8` isn't populated, and instead a 4 pin header has been fitted to `HL8` pins 1, 3, 5 and 7 to use the FPGA pins as GPIOs.

The fact that `R584` and `R669` are fitted means that if headers were connected to `HL8` pins 2, 4, 6 and 8 they would serve as a ground reference for the adjacent GPIOs.

**Update**: As suggested by @bruin in a comment, the designer might have put `R584` on the schematic to allow for installing a LED array with the anode and cathode swapped such that +2.5 V connects to the anodes of LEDs assuming that:

- `R669` was removed.
- `R584` was replaced with a zero \$\Omega\$ resistor.

The effect would be that the LED will be on when FPGA pin is low.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. “R584...serves no purpose that I can see”: is it possible that the designer kept the possibility for installing the LED in opposite direction such that +2.5v connects to the anodes of LEDs...assuming that R669 will be removed? The effect is that LED will be on when PL pin is low (instead of high).

Comment: @bruin I have attempted to edit the answer to include your comment.